# How can I convert a string to an Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
[["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]]
```

That's my string and I want to convert it to:

```
arr[0] = ["SFO"....
arr[1] = ["LAX"...
```

**EDIT**

Let me clarify:

```
var str = '[["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]]'
```

Comment: `["SFO,37.77493...` is already an array.

Comment: `var arr = eval('[["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]]');` should give you what you are looking for. `arr[0] = ["SFO"...`

Comment: I've heard that `eval` is evil and a terrible terrible thing to use. (http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/145037-why-eval-evil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**JSON.parse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON):

```
JSON.parse('[["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]]')
```

IE7 and below needs:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8.]>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

JSON.parse converts a string into a javascript object. Array's are objects. The string above will parse into an Array:

```
var array = JSON.parse('[["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]]')
alert ( typeof array ); // object
alert ( array instanceof Array); // true
```

Comment: This will convert to JSON, not an array

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [["SFO",37.77493,-122.41942],["LAX",34.05223,-118.24368]];
console.log(arr[0]); // ["SFO", 37.77493, -122.41942]
console.log(arr[1]); // ["LAX", 34.05223, -118.24368]
```